# Count if with 2 conditions - Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by

I'm having some trouble solving this, so I come here for your help.

I have a dataframe with many columns, and I want to count how many cells of a specific column meet the condition of another column. In Excel this would be count.if, but I can't figure it out exactly for my problem. Let me give you an example.

```
Names    Detail

John      B
John      B
John      S
Martin    S
Martin    B
Robert    S
```

In this df for example there are 3 "B" and 3 "S" in total.

How can I get how many "B" and "S" there are for each name in column A?

Im trying to get a result dataframe like

```
         B      S
John     2      1
Martin   1      1
Robert   0      1
```

I tried

```
b_var = sum(1 for i in df['Names'] if i == 'John') 
s_var = sum(1 for k in df['Detail'] if k == 'B')
```

and then make a for? but I don't know how to do both conditions at a time, or is it better a groupby approach?

Thanks!!

Comment: pd.crosstab(df.Names,df.Detail)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.pivot_table(index='Names', columns='Detail', aggfunc=len)
```

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='Names', columns='Detail', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)` correct answer but may be need explaination. otherwise HW